# How to apply WHERE filter when calling to_json preserving the :includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have the followin Ruby + Rails code

```
render :json =>  enterprise.to_json(:include => { :v3_passengers => { :include => [:cost_center, :restrictions]}})
```

And I need to apply a WHERE filter using one of the fields of the v3_passengers model before rendering it as json (for example "where v3_passenger.id = 2345")

I have tried this

```
render :json => enterprise.includes(:v3_passengers).where(enterprise_country: Thread.current['CurrentBehaviour'].COUNTRY).includes(:cost_center, :restrictions).to_json
```

But is not working, I have looked arround whitout any look in how to achieve this.

**UPDATE**

This are how the models are related

```
class Enterprise < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :v3_passengers


class V3Passenger < GlobalDB
    has_many :restrictions
    belongs_to :cost_center
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. First you need to filter by `joins` or `includes`:

```
foo = enterprise.joins(:v3_passengers).where(v3_passengers: {enterprise_country: Thread.current['CurrentBehaviour'].COUNTRY})
```

or (prefered includes, since you are going to need `v3_passengers` )

```
foo = enterprise.includes(:v3_passengers).where(v3_passengers: {enterprise_country: Thread.current['CurrentBehaviour'].COUNTRY})
```

---

#### 2. Then `include` the other nodes you need in the [`to_json`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json):

```
foo.to_json(include: [v3_passengers: { include: [:cost_center, :restrictions] } ])
```

---

#### Final Result:

```
render :json => enterprise.joins(:v3_passengers).where(v3_passengers: {enterprise_country: Thread.current['CurrentBehaviour'].COUNTRY}).to_json(include: [v3_passengers: { include: [:cost_center, :restrictions] } ])
```

Comment: I have just tried this but the result is empty. Is not producing any valid JSON

Comment: Can you post the associations between the models

Comment: The associations have been included in the question

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that:

```
model.includes(:other_model).to_json
```

Isn't the same as:

```
model.to_json(include: :other_model)
```

So your first attempt is giving you all the fields of Enterprise, V3Passenger, Restriction and CostCenter in the output. Your second attempt is just giving you fields of Enterprise.

One potential fix is:

```
enterprise.joins(:v3_passengers).where("v3_passengers.id=?",2345).to_json(include: :v3_passengers)
```

(Including the other tables of course.)

This will give you JSON for all the Enterprises with v3_passengers.id=2345, including JSON for all their V3Passengers (even the V3Passengers who don't have id 2345).

If you only want to include V3Passengers who match the where clause then you need to add a scoped association to the model:

```
has_many :v3_passengers_where_id_2345, -> { where id: 2345 }
```

And then use that association when doing the JSON conversion:

```
enterprise.joins(:v3_passengers).where("v3_passengers.id=?",2345).to_json(include: :v3_passengers_where_id_2345)
```

This will give you JSON for enterprises who have v3_passengers.id=2345, including only their V3Passengers who have id 2345.

Answer (score 1):

The second shot is close to working variant.

```
render :json => enterprise.v3_passengers.where(enterprise_country: Thread.current['CurrentBehaviour'].COUNTRY).includes(:cost_center, :restrictions).to_json
```

Try to use some relation.
For more clear answer add your key models listings, Enterprice and passengers models.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. For some reason now the restriccions of the passenger are not being included in the result, even when they exist in the database

Answer (score 1):

if you need the enterprise attributes in the resulting json:

```
render :json => enterprise.joins(:v3_passengers).where("v3_passengers.enterprise_country = ?", Thread.current['CurrentBehaviour'].COUNTRY).to_json(include: [v3_passengers: { include: [:cost_center, :restrictions] } ])
```

if you just need the passengers:

```
render :json => enterprise.v3_passengers.where(enterprise_country: Thread.current['CurrentBehaviour'].COUNTRY).includes(:cost_center, :restrictions).to_json( include: [:cost_center, :restrictions])
```

Comment: I need the v3_passengers atributes and include the cost center and restriccions too.

Comment: the second render should include the passenger, cost center and restriction attributes. Does it work for you ?